# Unable to change parent site for Stack Exchange Chat

Tags: bug, chat

When I go to my profile on chat.stackexchange.com, it says Parent site Area51 and I would like to change this site to Raspberry Pi.
I click "Chanhe? and it brings up an empty text field.
I have tried typing "Raspberry Pi", "raspberrypi.stackexchange.com", etc... but nothing works.
Is this supposed to be a drop-down not a text field?
The reason I want to change parent sites is because I only from 26 rep on Area51 but I ⠓ 113 on Raspberry Pi.
See screen shot below:

[image]

Comment: I could give it a poke if you wish, and help you change your parent site. Mods can reparent users.

Comment: Thanks, If you could change it to Raspberry Pi that would be great.

Comment: It is done. Looks that way from my end anyway :p

Comment: Thanks, I can confirm you have changed it successfully.

Answer (score 6):

Probably something going on there but I kinda just ended up assisting OP by setting their parent site for them.

I'd lean towards some mobile view/browser interaction strangeness, but that's out of my wheelhouse.

Comment: I have tried on two different devices. Does the screen shot I attached to the question show the text field I was talking about?